# Make UISearchBar first responder when View Loads

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, first-responder

I have a simple `UIViewController` and a `UISearchBar`, when the view loads I want to have the search bar become the first responder right away so that the keyboard is showing and they can start typing their query right away. I tried doing it in `viewWillAppear` like below without any luck:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [productSearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Is there another place that I should be calling `becomeFirstResponder` on the `UISearchBar` or should I be calling something else entirely?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Move this to `-viewDidAppear` and it should be fine. `-becomeFirstResponder` pulls up the keyboard (as you note), and you shouldn't do animations before you're onscreen. You can get weird interactions.

If it's not doing anything at all, then almost certainly `productSearchBar` is an IBOutlet and you've forgotten to actually tie it to the `UISearchBar` in Interface Builder. This is the #1 reason for "nothing happens" in UI.

Note that you shouldn't be accessing your ivars this way; you should make it a property and refer only to `self.productSearchBar`. Apple has finally posted a correct explanation of this in their [Memory Management of Nib Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/index.html). Never access your ivars outside of an accessor or `-dealloc`. This rule will save you many hours of debugging.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that did the trick. The link on Memory Management is a great help as well, I'll fix that up.